# AnthillPro - CCTray integration

Tags: build, automation, status, cctray, anthill

Does anyone know if you can use CCTray (or an equivalent) with AnthillPro?  I'm not finding a lot of documentation and am new to using AHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use CCTray type tools with AnthillPro. You would need to create a custom report to generate the XML though.

Shoot me an email at eric@urbancode.com I may be able to write this later in the week.

Otherwise, you could experiment with report writing.

You can find the cc xml format here: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CI/Multiple+Project+Summary+Reporting+Standard

Example AP report code that iterates over each build workflow and spits out data about the latest build is here: https://bugs.urbancode.com/browse/AHPSCRIPTS-13

The "Recent Build Life Activity (RSS)" report that I think ships with the product would give you an XML example.